# Find DOM element containing string matching regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex, search, dom

I need to find on HTML page all text fragments matching specific regular expression (that is, I need to ignore tags so that `'< span>First name: < /span>< br/>< b>John< /b>'` will match `'First name: John'`), and than highlight these found fragments (by decorating with new elements and applying custom css styles) and be able to locate these fragments, e.g. be able to scroll these into view.
Functionality is similar to what Skype browser plugin is doing with phone numbers found on page.

Comment: Do you have code that isn't working, or is this a "give me teh codez" question? What have you tried?

Comment: I need to find approach, I can do coding. If its solved already and code is available - even better.

Comment: It seems jQuery can do this with with :contains() selector. maybe its logic can be redefined to use regexp search instead of substring search.

Comment: Walk the DOM recursively, checking against the `data` of text nodes (nodeType of 3).

Comment: Mark, yes, thats what I was thinking about - walk Dom and pass symbols as input to some parser, maybe generated with tool like ANTLR specifically for my case, not RE.

Comment: [Jake Archibald](https://jakearchibald.com/) posted a [solution](http://jsbin.com/walaga/edit?html,js,output) to this using generators.

Answer (score 2):

You can either recursively walk down the DOM looking at the *textContent* or *innerText* property (as appropriate) of elements, or you can use loop over the collection returned by *getElementsByTagName*. Either way, once you have identified the text and the parent element, you need to work out how to replace it.

What are your requirements for document structure in the replacement if the string is split over one or more othere elements?

Comment: I'd argue that using a node-centric approach vs. a string-centric one will yield more portability. Besides, that's the aspect of the DOM most people have trouble with :).

Comment: Yes, but the OP wants the string even if it's split over more than one element, so just looking at text nodes won't do the job. I don't know how he intends dealing with split strings, but at least the above method will find the closest ancestor that has the whole string.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) to get the `<b>` tags containing `John` that come after a `<span>` tag that contains `First name:`, and then for instance apply a style:

```
$("span:contains('First name:') ~ b:contains('John')").css('color','red');
```

Here is a running example: http://jsfiddle.net/XzwNj/

Comment: It was just an example, not specific case

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

`document.body.innerHTML.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/g, '')`

Comment: That will not only destroy every listener that has been dynamically added, it will likely screw up elements, attributes and properties in different ways in different browsers for any page with non-trivial content.

Comment: I need to keep information on where in DOM my search results are located, or I can do document.body.innerText.match() - not what I need.